# Handling accidental multiple clicks in Java

Tags: java, javascript, swing, user-interface, click

When user clicks on the screen, a request is made to the database layer to store the data. However, when user accidentally double clicks or multiple clicks within a very short amount of time(like less than a second), multiple requests are being made to the database layer to store the same data. This is creating unwanted duplicates in the database.

The backend does have a check to see if a record already exists before inserting...But since multiple clicks on the screen generate requests at the same time, this unique check in the service is doing no good as it does not find the record.

How can I handle this situation with all the quick multiple clicks?

Answer (score 1):

Usually a task like this would block anything else from being started, so it would be good to `setEnabled(false)` on the button being used to submit the entry. This will ensure any button clicks will be ignored. Just call `someButton.setEnabled(true)` when the query returns.